# Can a table be in 3NF with no primary keys?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

> **1.**
>   A table is automatically in 3NF if **one** of the following holds:
>   (i) If a relation consists of two attributes.
>   (ii) If 2NF table consists of only one non key attribute.
>
> **2.**
>   If X → A is a dependency, then the table is in 3NF, if one of the following conditions exists:
>   (i) If X is a superkey
>   (ii) If A is a part of superkey

I got the above claims from [this site](http://www.edugrabs.com/3nf-third-normal-form).

I think that in both the claims, 2nd subpoint is wrong.

The first one says that a table in 2NF will be in 3NF if we have all non-key attributes and the table is in 2NF.

Consider the example R(A,B,C) with dependency A->B.

Here we have no candidate key, so all attributes are non-prime attributes and the relation is not in 3NF but in 2NF.

The second one says that for a dependency of the form X->A if A is part of a super key then it's in 3NF.

Consider the example R(A,B,C) with dependencies A->B, B->C . Here a CK is {A}. Now one of the super keys can be AC and the RHS of FD B->C contains part of AC but still the above relation R is not in 3NF.

I think it should be A should be part of a **candidate key** and not **super key**.

Am I correct?

Also can a particular relation be in 1NF, 3NF or 2NF if there are **no functional dependencies** present?

Comment: Your reasoning and even your statements are not clear in the second half.  I did try to improve the English without changing your apparent intended meaning. PS See my edits to my answer since I replaced this comment by an updated version.

Comment: That link's definitions of transitive FD & 3NF are wrong. And its method of decomposition is wrong. And its method of using transitive FDs & decomposition to get to 3NF is wrong. Use a textbook. Dozens are free online & there are academic slides & courses.

Answer (score 1):

A CK (candidate key) is a superkey that contains no smaller superkey. A superkey is a unique set of attributes. A relation is a set of tuples. So every relation has a superkey, the set of all attributes. So it has at least one CK.

A FD (functional dependency) holds by definition when each value of a determining set of attributes appears always with the same value for its determined set. Every relation value or variable satisfies "trivial" FDs, the ones where the determined set is a subset of the determining set. Every set of attributes determines {}. So every relation satisfies at least one FD. However, the correct forms of definitions typically specifically talk about *non-trivial* FDs. Don't use the web, use textbooks, of which dozens are free online, although not all are well-written. Many textbooks also forget about FDs where the determinant and/or determined set is {}.

Your first point is not a correct definition of 3NF. Since its phrased "if..." instead of "if and only if", maybe it's not trying to be a definition. However, it is still wrong. (i) is wrong because a relation with two attributes is not in 3NF if one is a CK and the other has the same value in every tuple, ie it is determined by {}.

Similarly the second point is not a proper definition and also even if you treat it as only a consequence of 3NF (if...) it's false. It would be a definition if it used *if and only if* and talked about an FD *that holds* and it said it was a *non-trivial* FD and some other things were fixed.

Since those are neither correct definitions nor correct implications, there's a unlimited number of ways to disprove them. Read a book (or my posts) and get correct definitions.

---

Some comments re your reasoning:

> First one says that, a table in 2NF will be in 3NF if we have all non key attributes and table is in 2NF.

I have no idea why you think that.

> Here we have no candidate key

There's always one or more CKs. You need to read a definition of CK. There are also non-brute-force algorithms for finding them all.

> Second one says that, for the dependency of form X->A if A is part of super key then it's in 3NF.

I have no idea why you think that.

> A should be part of candidate key and not super key.

A correct defintion like the second point does normally say "... or (ii) A-X is part of a CK". But I can't follow your reasoning.

Sound reasoning involves starting from assumptions and writing new statements that we know are true because we applied a definition, a previously proved statement (theorem) or a sound rule of reasoning, eg from 'A implies B' and 'A' we can derive 'B'. You seem to need to read about how to do that.