# 4NF decomposition with MVD

Tags: database, database-normalization

Consider the table with attributes A and B

```
 A                B



222              Jack

222              Jill

222              Joe
```

Here A ->-> B holds true. My book says that the above relation is in 4NF.

I don't understand how it can be in 4NF as for a relation to be in 4NF, A should be a super key for that relation if there is a MVD of form A->->B.

Here how is A a super key ? For same value of A (222), we have multiple values of B.

Comment: If `A` is a key column and `B` contains no repeated names for a given key, then this table has to be in 4NF, because there are no non trivial multivalued dependencies.  I think you would need a third column to illustrate breaking 4NF.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you tell me how is A->-> B trivial?

Comment: Normalization (including 4NF) is about eliminating redundancies in your table.  If `A` be a key, and there are no repeated `(A, B)` relations, then the table is in 4NF.  As I mentioned, because it is in 4NF, I would have to add a third column to show what is not 4NF.

Comment: Ok. Wikipedia says that if union of A and B gives us attributes of entire relation, then it's trivial MVD. Now if you see the example in wikipedia of restaurant, we can combine two MVD's by union property . So new MVD would be restaurant -> pizza delivery(pizza and delivery are two attributes). Now even here union is entire relation but wikipedia says it's not in 4NF. Why is it so ? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form

Comment: Hi Zephyr, that Wikipedia does a great job of explaining 4NF, and I'm not sure that I can do any better.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understood the entire article of wikipedia. But the point is they have not considered union property of MVD and treated each MVD separately. Did you read my previous comment?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You might be interested in my answer. Re your comments, non-trivial MVDs do hold. (But the table isn't in 4NF & {A} isn't a CK.)

Comment: @philipxy Nice answer, but I have yet to encounter a real world scenario where 4NF is of concern.

Comment: Your question & comments do not get definitions correct. (That's true for other questions of yours.) If you have a question about the wiki article you should post a new question. But first you should apply the correct definition of 4NF.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen [That's only because it is usually so obvious semantically when 4NF & 5NF are violated--it requires that a table meaning is the AND of independent meanings--that people avoid violations intuitively.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47735550/3404097) (Just because violations end up being rare doesn't make them unproblematic/unimportant.)

Comment: Maybe you don't mean the *value* is in 4NF (it isn't). Maybe you mean that it's an example value of a base relation you know is in 4NF. It would help if you would explain where you got this. Eg there's a similar variable in Elrasmi-Navathe 6th edition Figure 15. An MVD held in *a different base relation* decomposed to that one. There is no theorem that a MVD holds in a component that has the same attributes. (The definition of MVD involves *all* the attributes of its relation.) But the MVD still held. But because it's trivial. They even say that. That's why {A] -->> {B} holds here.

Answer (score -2):

**That relation isn't even in 2NF**

> My book says that the above relation is in 4NF

Why do you say that? What is your book? That relation value has sole CK {B} but satisfies the FD {} -> A which is a partial dependency of a non-prime attribute on a CK so it isn't even in 2NF.

**Your implication is wrong**

> for a relation to be in 4NF, A should be a super key for that relation if there is a MVD of form A->->B

Let us simplify that complicated phrasing: if a relation is in 4NF then if MVD (multi-valued dependency) {A} ->> {B} holds then {A} is a superkey.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form):

> A table is in 4NF if and only if, for every one of its non-trivial multivalued dependencies X ↠ Y, X is a superkey

This tells us that if a relation is in 4NF then if *non-trivial* MVD X ->> Y holds then X is a superkey.

So it doesn't tell us what you claimed. You left out "non-trivial".

But since the relation isn't in 4NF the inner implication doesn't matter.

**That MVD is trivial so if we *had* 4NF then the inner implication wouldn't apply**

In your relation {A} ->> {B} holds, but it is *trivial* since {A} U {B} is the set of all attributes and

> A trivial multivalued dependency X ↠ Y is one where either Y is a subset of X, or X and Y together form the whole set of attributes of the relation

So if the relation were in 4NF then {A} would not have to be a superkey.

(The (trivial) (binary) JD (join dependency) corresponding to the MVD is *{{A}, {A, B}}, ie the relation is the join of its projections on {A} & {A, B}.)

***Other* MVDs hold that violate 4NF**

The definition tells us that a relation being in 4NF requires that if a *non-trivial* MVD X ->> Y holds then X is a superkey.

If you list all the MVDs relevant to that relation then you will find that they are all trivial except {} ->> {A} and {} ->> {B}. It happens that both of those hold. (They express the same condition, that the same JD holds, that the relation is a certain join.) But {} isn't a superkey. So 4NF is violated.

(In terms of JDs: The only possible non-trivial binary JD is *{{A}, {B}}, which happens to hold. But that is not implied by the CKs, ie it doesn't have to hold when the CK set is {{B}}, ie (per Fagin's membership algorithm) the join of its two elements is not on a common column set that includes a CK of both. So the relation is not in 4NF.)

But we already know 4NF is violated, because we know 2NF is violated.

Comment: How is {} -> B valid ? How can nothing or empty set determine B?

Comment: I didn't say {} -> B. I said {} ->> {B}. Plug {} & {B} into a definition of when a MVD holds. Eg the relation is {A} U {} join {} U {B}. I did say {} -> A. Plug {} & A into a definition of when a FD (determining an attribute) holds. (Unfortunately, many textbooks & of course web pages have wrong & sloppy definitions.)

Comment: PS I addressed FDs with {} in [this answer to a question by you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47632874/3404097). (Also I wrote about proper reasoning & use of terms, definitions & theorems.)

Comment: For downvoters: Please first say what you think is wrong, and read my last comment on the question re NFs of values vs variables.